# $scope.myFunc() is not a function

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to ng-bind $scope.span00, span01, span10, and so on in a grid.

```
$scope.span01 = 'test'; // this works fine
```

Now for the ng-click...

```
$scope.clickedOn = function(row, column) {

  var gridLocation = function() { return 'span'.concat(row).concat(column); } // returns span01
  $scope.gridLocation() = 'test'; // says $scope.gridLocation() is not a function.
}
```

It's saying it's not a function. What do I do here?

Comment: Add the function to the $scope

Comment: your code looks strange, 
just to answer to your question: **you declared your function without assignin it to the `$scope`, so, call it just as `gridLocation()`.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the function does not exist on `$scope`. This is what you need to do:

```
$scope.gridLocation = function (row, column) {
    return 'span'.concat(row).concat(column);
};

$scope.clickedOn = function (row, column) {
    $scope.gridLocation(row, column);
};
```

**Edit**

To do what you asked for in the comments (I hope I understood correctly):

```
$scope.clickedOn = function (row, column) {
    $scope[$scope.gridLocation(row, column)] = 'test';
};
```

Comment: Love it! Much cleaner looking than nested function declarations. Thank you :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Comment: "Invalid left-hand side in assignment"   $scope.gridLocation(row, column) = 'test';

Comment: Do you mean ``const test = $scope.gridLocation(row, column);`` ? I am not sure what you are trying to do right now.

Comment: I modified my response

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145852/discussion-between-tyler-l-and-vladimir-zdenek).