# $scope.myFunc is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting $scope.myFunc() is not a function error in the console. Below is my angularjs code. The answer on [$scope.myFunc() is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44364912/scope-myfunc-is-not-a-function) SO post states "Because the function does not exist on $scope". Is that what is going here? Thank you. https://codepen.io/centem/pen/JjobPEW?editors=1010 is a codepen of my compete code.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController',
function ($scope, $http, $filter) {

  $scope.myFunc() = function() {
    const fname = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
    const lname = document.getElementById('lastname').value;

    console.log(`${fname} ${lname}`);
  };

});
```

Comment: Try `$scope.myFunc = function() { ... }`, ie remove the `()` after `myFunc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove `()` from `$scope.myFunc()` and then retry.

Try this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController',
function ($scope, $http, $filter) {    
  $scope.myFunc = function() {
    const fname = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
    const lname = document.getElementById('lastname').value;    
    console.log(`${fname} ${lname}`);
  };    
});
```

Comment: @JigoroKano thanks for accepting my answer. Please upvote it :)

Answer (score 0):

1. `$scope.myFunc` is an identifier here, which is being assigned function written next to it.
2. If you see, `()` next to anything, it means identifier is being as an function.

By combining 1 and 2, it means that in statement `$scope.myFunc()`, you are essentially invoking function as well, which at this point of tiem is `undefined`, which is not a function.

To fix this,

```
$scope.myFunc = function() {
const fname = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
const lname = document.getElementById('lastname').value;

console.log(`${fname} ${lname}`);
};
```